# Static linking with Boost and ncurses

Tags: c++, boost, static-libraries, ncurses

I am in the process of making a basic role-playing game. I want to include the Boost libraries statically so that the people who run my game do not need to have them. I researched and looked-up that all you have to do is add `-static` to the command-line compile, so my command is like this:

```
$ g++ -static -o karthas *.o -lncurses -lmenu -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem
```

But apparently the `-static` is affecting ncurses. I am getting a whole bunch of errors, most of which are undefined reference to 'SP'.

Is it possible to just do a static link to Boost and not ncurses? How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Does the usual dynamic linking work? Are you able to build and run your program without static linking?

Comment: @chrisaycock yes dynamic linking works on my system because it has the bost library installed. but what i want to have happen is me able to distribute my program without requiring the user to install the boost libraries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can choose which libraries will be linked statically and which will be linked dynamically by putting either `-Wl,-static` or `-Wl,-Bdynamic` before their name.

For example, with:

```
g++  -o karthas *.o -Wl,-static -lmenu -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -Wl,-Bdynamic -lncurses
```

The menu, boost_system and boost_filesystem libraries will be linked statically and ncurses dynamically.

(But you can also distribute the boost dlls with your executable, and not link anything statically).

Comment: That is perfect! Thanks. A couple more things though. Now when i run the executable it says error while loading shared libraries: libtinfo.so.5. what is that from? and can i statically link that?

About your last statement, how would i distribute them with my executable? and how would i compile it differently? also, i am on linux so they arent dll's

Comment: i think the libtinfo.so.5 is from ncurses. so i know this post isnt related to that but am i able to statically link ncurses too? i didnt realize ncurses was a dynamically linking library

Comment: i found out that i can add -DNCURSES_STATIC to the .o creation to make the static ncurses possible. but then i get a cannot find -lgcc_s error. Ill look more into that

Comment: To distribute the .so, you can pass a `-rpath` option with `$ORIGIN` to the linker to specify directory where you want to store them relative to the executable directory (see the corresponding section on [`man -s 8 ld.so`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld.so) ).

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense but where do i put the -rpaty? could you give an example? I tried putting it with g++ but it says unrecognized option. Sorry for all these questions but i am grateful for your help! also, i am doing this in a Makefile. is that ok to do?

Comment: Everything is already explained with an example for gcc, in the section "$ORIGIN and rpath" of the link I gave at the end of my previous comment.

Comment: Im sorry, i read the man page but i somehow went right over the example

Comment: Ok so i think i got it working. I didnt realize at first that i had to define ORIGIN. So am i right in thinking that this will let anyone who has my executable and the folder containing the .so's run it without error?

edit: i just tested it on another machine and it cant find the libraries even though they are in ../lib relative to the executable

Comment: Well i am all good i believe. Thanks a lot to all of those who helped! The only thing is that you have to run the executable in its directory, which is not a big deal ig. Thanks again

Comment: `$ORIGIN` is not a shell or a make variable but a linker variable that represents the executable directory, the string has to arrive unchanged to gcc. You have to escape the $ (with "$$") when used in the Makefile so that make doesn't try to replace it by a value (`-Wl,-rpath,'$$ORIGIN/../lib'`).

Comment: sorry to bug you again, i really am, but when i did what you said, during compile it is saying that there is no such file or directory when there is. ../lib exists from where the makefile is and where the executable is. any ideas?

Comment: Wow, so i figured out what was wrong, i was putting a space in between -rpath, and '$$ORIGIN/../lib'
Thanks so much for all of your help alex.

Answer (score 0):

But looking at [this](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6375), it seems that you are not alone, either that, or I found your issue. But [this](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/6146), might have your solution, either way, good luck.
Btw, some boost libraries are little more than inline functions that are imported when included in the file.

Comment: Not all of them. Some of them, like filesystem, are compiled binaries.

Comment: Depends on the libraries.  Some boost libraries do have compiled components (regex, test, etc)

Comment: @JamesMichaelHare Right. Do you happen to know how to fix my problem?

Comment: Fixed it. Now should be more accurate.