# Statically Linking NCurses Gives Error, for use in BusyBox environment

Tags: linux, g++, static-linking, busybox

I wrote a very simple ncurses program to be run in BusyBox environment. However, it seems like that I cannot get my program to compile with everything. I used:

```
g++ menu.cpp -ohello -lncurses  --> Works fine
g++ -static menu.cpp -ohello -lncurses --> Undefined reference to SP (many times)
```

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9708086/static-linking-with-boost-and-ncurses) but it ignores linking to ncurses. I need a very single executable. My targeted environment is fixed, so I do not concern portability.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should paste the exact compiler calls and the exact error messages that you are getting.
2. Do you have a static version of the `ncurses` library?
3. More importantly, do you have a static version of the `ncurses` library compiled for your target environment? For example your target environment may be using `ulibc` instead of `glibc` or it could even be a whole different platform (hint: tell us what your target platform is).
4. Are you certain that you are compiling with the right flags? The compiler flags that you are showing seem more suited to compiling an application for use in the build host environment...

Comment: 1. It just cannot find ncurses library; hundreds of lines of: Undefined reference to SP .
2. No 3. Target environment is a x86 pc
4. NO I am not sure, that's why I am asking it here; how to make a single executable with no external dependency; everything included in a file